# O construtor File(String) cria um arquivo?

Tags: java

Quando usamos o método construtor `File f = new File(aquiVemOEnderecoDoArquivo)`, caso o arquivo não exista, ele é criado?

Comment: @renanzin tem certeza disso? `An abstract representation of file and directory pathnames.`

Comment: não @ArticunoL  ;) apaguei aqui.

Comment: Você chegou a rodar o código e ver se ele cria o arquivo? De qualquer forma, o arquivo não é criado, tanto que há o método [`exists`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists--) para verificar se o arquivo de fato existe, e o método [`createNewFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile--) para criá-lo (e há também `FileOutputStream` e `FileWriter`, que escrevem no arquivo - e criam, caso não exista). Mas só fazer `new File` não cria nada

Comment: Eu sinceramente acho os negativos meu injusto nesse caso, a documentação não é tão clara em relação a isso, ela não diz de forma explicita. A duvida é valida.

Comment: @ArticunoL também acho

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44523347/java-new-file-does-not-create-file

Comment: Agora entendi a pergunta, mas creio que não pois olha esse trecho da documentação do File(string): `"If the given string is the empty string, then the result is the empty abstract pathname."`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não, o construtor da classe `File` cria uma instância representativa do caminho que você informa do arquivo ou diretório, mas nada é criado no *File System* pelo construtor, como pode ser visto no grifo abaixo, retirado da [própria documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/File.html):

> **Instances of this class may or may not denote an actual file-system object such as a file or a directory.** If it does denote such an object then that object resides in a partition. A partition is an operating system-specific portion of storage for a file system. A single storage device (e.g. a physical disk-drive, flash memory, CD-ROM) may contain multiple partitions. The object, if any, will reside on the partition named by some ancestor of the absolute form of this pathname.

Em tradução livre:

> **Instâncias dessa classe podem denotar ou não um objeto real do sistema de arquivos, como um arquivo ou um diretório.** Se ele denotar tal objeto, então esse objeto reside em uma partição. Uma partição é uma parte específica do sistema operacional de armazenamento para um sistema de arquivos. Um único dispositivo de armazenamento (por exemplo, uma unidade de disco físico, memória flash, CD-ROM) pode conter várias partições. O objeto, se houver, residirá na partição nomeada por algum ancestral da forma absoluta desse nome de caminho.

Se quiser comprovar na prática, pode rodar o código abaixo, que irá criar uma instância de um arquivo de texto inexistente na sua pasta de usuário. Primeiro irá checar a existência, depois irá criar o arquivo e checar novamente. Você pode acompanhar com sua pasta de usuário aberta.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileClassTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String userDir = System.getProperty("user.home");

        File  file = new File(userDir + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "someUnknownFile.txt");

        System.out.println(file.exists());

        file.createNewFile();

        System.out.println(file.exists());

    }
}
```

Lembrando que o código só irá retornar false na primeira vez que for executado, pois ao executar `file.createNewFile();`, o arquivo será criado no File System.

Answer (score 1):

Não cria.

A documentação diz o seguinte:

> File(String pathname)
>
> Creates a new File instance by converting the given pathname string into an abstract pathname.

Como o texto informa, é criado um caminho abstrato, ou seja, fisicamente inexistente. O arquivo em si é criado de fato apenas quando você utiliza métodos que **escrevam** (ou preparam a escrita) efetivamente no disco. O código abaixo permite provar isso:

```
File f = new File("teste.txt");
System.out.println(f.exists()); //false
OutputStream anOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(f.getName());
System.out.println(f.exists()); //true
```

Answer (score 0):

Baseado nos comentários da publicação e em alguns minutos que eu passei pensando no assunto, cheguei a conclusão que o contrutor `File(String path)` não cria um arquivo. Posso afirmar isso pois se o construtor criasse o arquivo, a existência da função `exists()` e `createNewFile()` seria inútil.